# SQL Not Like Statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

How can I select table from sys.tables where table name does not containt special word (which pass in parameters).

I want to select all tables where its contains word 'customer' but not those who ends with 'old'
in name.

**TableName In DB**

customer1
customer2
customer3
customerold1
customerold2

**Output Wanted**

customer1
customer2
customer3

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables
    WHERE TableName LIKE '%customer%'
      AND TableName NOT LIKE '%old' -- note the lack of trailing '%'
```

[LIKE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have a parameter for your special word, you can do:

```
WHERE TableName LIKE @specialWord + '%'
AND TableName NOT LIKE '%' + @specialWord + '%old%'
```